# My form field percieves String input as invalid

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form that keep track of prospect and current deals being made with a sale consultant. However, I am stuck at a process of creating a deal because django keep giving me error of "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:" when I try to input customer last name with strings. The form work when i try creating with integer lastname though.

**Models.py**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length = 20,blank = True)
    nick_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20,blank = True)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex = r'^\+?\d{10,15}$',message = "Phone number invalid")
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex],max_length=16)
    second_phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex],max_length=16,blank = True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Deal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length = 50,blank=True)
    booked_car = models.ForeignKey('BookedCar', on_delete = models.SET_NULL, 
null = True)
    prospect = models.ForeignKey('Customer', on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null = True)
    is_credit = models.BooleanField()
    car_price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    final_accessories = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    final_campaign = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    final_spending = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

**views.py**

```
def booking_create(request,customer_id):
    customer = get_object_or_404(Customer,pk=customer_id)
    template_name = 'customerDB/booking_create.html'


    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookingCreate(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            customer.deal_set.create(name = form.cleaned_data['name'],
                lastname = form.cleaned_data['lastname'],
                booked_car = form.cleaned_data['booked_car'],
                is_credit = form.cleaned_data['is_credit'],
                car_price = form.cleaned_data['car_price'],
                final_accessories = form.cleaned_data['lastname'],
                final_campaign = form.cleaned_data['final_campaign'],
                final_spending = form.cleaned_data['final_spending']
                )
    else:
        form = BookingCreate(initial= {'name':customer.name})

    return render(request,template_name,{'form':form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class BookingCreate(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Deal
        fields = '__all__'
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:customer_id>/',views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:customer_id>/follow_up/', views.follow_up,name = 'follow_up'),
    path('<int:customer_id>/transfer/',views.transfer_view,name= 'transfer_view'),
    path('<int:customer_id>/booking/',views.booking_create,name= 'booking_create'),
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**booking_create.html**

```
{% block content %}
<html>

<form action="" method="post">
    {%csrf_token %}
    <h3>booking detail</h3>
    <br/>
    <table>
    {{form.as_table}}
    </table>
    <br/>
    <input type = "submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</form> 
    {% endblock %}
```

**full traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Top\project\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Top\project\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Top\project\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Top\project\mysite\customerDB\views.py", line 199, in booking_create
    final_spending = form.cleaned_data['final_spending']
  File "C:\Users\Top\project\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 623, in create
    return super(RelatedManager, self.db_manager(db)).create(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Top\project\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Top\project\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 417, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\Top\project\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 729, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\Top\project\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 759, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\Top\project\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 842, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "C:\Users\Top\project\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 880, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "C:\Users\Top\project\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Top\project\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1125, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\Users\Top\project\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1280, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "C:\Users\Top\project\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1233, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "C:\Users\Top\project\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1233, in <listcomp>
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "C:\Users\Top\project\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1232, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "C:\Users\Top\project\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1172, in prepare_value
    value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\Top\project\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 767, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "C:\Users\Top\project\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 762, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\Top\project\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1826, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Bush'
```

Comment: Paste your `urls.py` and other models.

Comment: You need to show the full traceback. What is it trying to convert to int?

Comment: I think you might be having problem with `booked_car = form.cleaned_data['booked_car'],`  while creating object. The `booked_car` needs to be an object or its integer pk.

Answer (score 1):

The error is almost certainly coming from this line:

```
final_accessories = form.cleaned_data['lastname'],
```

since `final_accessories` is supposed to be an integer, but you are passing the value of lastname.

To avoid issues like this, you should really rely on the ability of a ModelForm to create the whole instance for you. You can assign the Customer instance via the `commit=False` method:

```
if form.is_valid():
   deal = form.save(commit=False)
   deal.prospect = customer
   deal.save()
```

Comment: It worked ! Also, thank you for further explanation but why does  deal = form.save(commit=False) data doesnt have to be cleaned before saving ?

Comment: I don't understand your question - it does have to be cleaned, that's why we call is_valid().